# Pregamtch for any punctuation in a string

Tags: php, string, expression, preg-match

Im really struggling with the whole preg_match function.

I want to find out if a string has any punctuation except for a dash -. I want to be able to detect `!"%&*(){}[];:?/` so that i end up with a string of just letters and numbers, except for the dash.

I have this `preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/", $_POST['title'])` hoever it doesnt really do much.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "except for the dash"? Do you want just letters and numbers? your question isn't clear

Comment: What about spaces? And letters with diacritics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax of your regex is `/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/`

If you have some trouble to write regex, tools like https://regex101.com can be usefull

Comment: HI, thanks for this however i have tried this and i dont seem to get the right answers. My text is "This is a test, see what happens!" this should find the , and !.

Comment: preg_match function only return 1 (true) if found one or more special chars, If you want to found all specials chars in your string or 0 (false) if there is nothing. Note with this regex, space character is a special char. you need use preg_match_all with a `$matches` parameter (see : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all)

Comment: Sorted!! Just did a quick str_replace and removed and spaces between words as this was being picked up and causing the misleading results. The link you provided helped me notice this. Many thanks